# Could not be able to work with spring security java config

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm learning Spring Security, when configured using following configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContextConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/home/**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/dashboard/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/rest/users/**").hasRole("ADMIN").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }

     @Autowired
        public void registerGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth
              .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin")
                .password("admin")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
          }
}
```

and AppInitializer is

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {  

        WebApplicationContext rootContext = getWebApplicationContext();         

        // add the dispatcher servlet and map it to /
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(rootContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "springDispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setAsyncSupported(true);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncoding", characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic security = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        security.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, "/*");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext)); 

    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getWebApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("pkj.to.config.classes");
        return context;
    }

}
```

login form is

```
<form action="<spring:url value='/login'/>" method="post">
    <input class="input-field" type='text' name='username' placeholder="admin name">
        <input class="input-field" type='password' name='password' placeholder="admin password" /><br>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />           
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

and controller is

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doShowHomePage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String adminLogin(Model model) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

with above configurations when I submit login form I'm redirected to login page again and again.

Comment: And what it the expected behavior?

Comment: Try to remove the `POST` handler on `/login`, i.e. `adminLogin` method. Spring Security provides that.